# Angular-Meteor - Store data returned by an API

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I am working an Angular-Meteor app which is some what similar to eCommerce site. I am using `publish-subscribe` to display products list. But on two pages, I have to get data from Facebook first, then I have to get user's favorite categories [like clothing, art etc.], user's liked product list and his current city and now according to all these details I have to display products list. So I am calling server side API from client and on server side, I am using `meteor.call` and returning data to the user.
For the first time, it will take time to load data. That is completely acceptable. But every time user tries to load these pages, it is hitting database. So is there any way to store all data is cache instead of hitting database every time?
I thought of storing data in `$rootscope`, but is it a good practice? Because products list may contain 100-200 products[I am using pagination and getting 5 products at one time] due to this entire Digest cycle had became very slow. So that's not an option for me as some other functionalities are dependent on Digest cycle. 
How exactly should I store products list, instead of hitting database every time? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You say you use publish and subscribe, but then also meteor.call. can you share the relevant code?

Comment: @tally I have used publish and subscribe on other pages.But on two pages, where I have to get data from user, I have not used publish and subscribe,instead I have used `meteor.call`.

Comment: using meteor publish-subscribe is using local cache (mini mongo is local cache), so just subscribe to your data.